# Assigned response data show [object object] React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, laravel-5, react-native

I am having a problem to iterate the validation errors that i am getting from server side (Laravel). I could get the errors response and assign in state errors array. But when i console.log the state it shows me [obeject object]. So i am unable to iterate the array. Can u guys kindly help ?

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            userName:'',
            userEmail:'', 
            userPassword:'',
            errors:[]               
        }
    }

axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: API_URL+'signup',
            data: {
                username: userName,
                email: userEmail,
                password: userPassword
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            var count = Object.keys(response.data.errors).length;
            if (count > 0) {
                console.log(response.data);
                var newState = []; 
                newState.push(response.data);
                this.setState({
                    errors: newState
                })
            }

            console.log("error = " + this.state.errors); // console output: error = [object Object]
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

// inside render function i have done following code to show the validation errors

```
render() {
    <Errors errors={this.state.errors} />
}

const Errors = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>{props.errors.map((error, i) => <Text key={i}>{error}</Text>)}</View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `newState.push(response.data.errors)` instead of `newState.push(response.data)` ?

Also, when printing `JSON` objects, you need to use `JSON.stringify`. So `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.errors))` would have displayed the `JSON` in readable `string` format

Comment: yea now i update: newState.push(JSON.stringify(response.data.errors)); and console.log(this.state.errors) ... it works fine. But doesnt show the error in view when state updates. @Lingaraju E V

Comment: Can you show me a sample response from the `AJAX` request? And did you update `newState.push(response.data)` to `newState.push(response.data.errors)`? I am assuming `response.data.errors` is an `Array`

Comment: this is my latest update: https://paste.laravel.io/cad3a4d1-767a-4aa0-8190-3239ec8ccb03

Comment: Hi, I have updated your code . Please check it out. As suspected your `response.data.errors` is not an `Array`. So you cannot just use `Array.map` on it. I have used `Object.keys` to enumerate through all the `keys` in your `errors` object and print their respective `error` messages.


https://paste.laravel.io/90b7baa5-09d4-4c6e-9bab-dc006fe20737

Comment: thank u so much. But your change in then() without pushing just assigning is not working. it shows " error = [object Object] " in console. I have declared errors in state as an Array.You can see in my above code. And also the UI doesnt update on any change.

Comment: That's strange. But as long I don't know the exact response that you get from the server, I cannot provide a valid solution.

Comment: [{"username":["The username field is required."],"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}]

this is what i am getting from server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157289/discussion-between-lingaraju-e-v-and-wahidsherief).

Answer (score 5):

> Not related to your question but for me it was quite a pathetic reason
>   why it was showing as [Object Object]. See below difference.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {       
   console.log("Data"+nextProps.payload.payloadData); // Display [Object Object]
   console.log(nextProps.payload.payloadData);  //  Display proper list
}
```

Comment: This answer deserves much more upvotes! Can anyone explain why object props cannot be clubbed with a string?